# Постановка запятой перед «и»

Tags: запятые, и

«Этот мужчина часто пил(,) и в довольно больших количествах, но его никогда не видели пьяным». В данном случае «и» начинает дополнение, которое можно легко опустить без потери смысла? Или «и» выступает в качестве слова «причём» (которое опущено)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В данном случае «и» начинает дополнение, которое можно легко опустить без потери смысла?

Да. Вернее, уточнение. Запятая **нужна**.

> Или «и» выступает в качестве слова «причём» (которое опущено)?

Не совсем выступает, но "причём" подразумевается по смыслу.

Это сложносочинённое предложение, а подлежащее и сказуемое просто пропущены (иначе союза "и" вообще бы не было):
*Этот мужчина часто пил, и [пил он] в довольно больших количествах.*

В следующем предложении запятая уже не нужна:
*Этот мужчина часто пил и в довольно больших количествах **ел**.*

Ещё интересный пример:
*Этот мужчина может выпить и 2 литра пива во время матча.* || Здесь "и" усилительная частица — запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Этот мужчина часто пил(,) и в довольно больших количествах, но его никогда не видели пьяным.

В первой части (Этот мужчина часто пил(,) и в довольно больших количествах) данного предложения "и в довольно больших количествах" - это присоединительный член в первой части.

Нет, я домового не видал, да его и видеть нельзя (Т.).

Здесь "да его и видеть нельзя" - присоединительное предложение.

Необходимы были всякие меры предосторожности, особенно если приходилось идти ночью.

Здесь "особенно если приходилось идти ночью" - придаточная часть 
сложноподчиненного предложения и выступает в роли присоединительной конструкции.

Comment: Вы бы всё-таки ответили, нужна запятая или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба варианта:

**1) Усилительная частица И:** *Этот мужчина часто пил **и в довольно больших количествах,** но его никогда не видели пьяным».* Обстоятельство не обособляется.

**1) Присоединительный союз И** (присоединительный член относится к первому предложению в составе ССП): *Этот мужчина часто пил, **и в довольно больших количествах,** но его никогда не видели пьяным.*

Семантика разная. В первом случае персонаж употреблял разные дозы (как небольшие, так и значительные), но держался вполне корректно. Во втором же случае он пил часто и помногу.

Comment: Усилительная частица не подходит по смыслу. "Довольно" указывает на уточнение: *пил, и довольно много*. Вот так да: *Этот мужчина часто пил и в больших количествах.* Но звучит плохо даже так. Гораздо лучше звучит с конкретным количеством: *Этот мужчина часто пил и по 2 литра.*

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы Вы отвечали на заданный вопрос: нужна в этом предложении запятая или нет. И объясняли ясно свою позицию. А то получается, что в тексте вопроса сам вопрос "перемешан" с доводами автора, а вы  точно так же оформляете ответ, которого я, к примеру, просто не вижу.  Литературная правка, собственные примеры - всё это дополнительный материал, а Вы им слишком увлекаетесь. Качество ответа вследствие этого не на уровне. Вы хотя бы перечитайте, что Вы написали. Причем тут ССП, пропущенные члены предложения и прочее? В художественной литературе это называется ПОТОКОМ СОЗНАНИЯ.

Comment: И по поводу комментария к моему ответу. Я привожу две структурные схемы с разным смыслом, ничего не меняя в предложении. Из этого ясно, что И может выполнять разные функции. А вы начинает рассказывать, что и как звучит в Вашем понимании. Хотите сравнить семантику слов "достаточно и довольно"? Так и говорите, причем доказывайте с помощью словарей, а не "звучания".  Вот когда будет вопрос, что лучше звучит, тогда и используйте такую схему ответа.

Comment: "Довольно" вообще не сочетается с усилительной частицей, которая больше подходит для конкретики. Надо же хоть чуть-чуть рассматривать стилистику, а не только грамматику. Никакой автор так бы предложение не составил. Если вы предоставляете несколько вариантов, очень желательно указать, какой ответ вероятнее и больше подходит по стилистике текста. При усилительной частице, вероятно, был бы перенос сказуемого: *Этот мужчина и в довольно больших количествах мог выпить.* Но "довольно" здесь избыточно и как лишнее. При постановке знаков предложение должно оставаться корректным во всех отношениях.

Comment: "*вопрос "перемешан" с доводами автора, а вы точно так же оформляете ответ*" — это подвопросы, на которые, считаю, отвечать надо обязательно на уровне с главным. Всегда так и делаю.

Comment: В данном случае нужно редактировать сам вопрос (хотя бы для себя),чтобы понять его смысл.  Как я считаю, автор спрашивает: 1) этот оборот  является необособленным членом предложения (кстати,  обстоятельством, не дополнением)? 2) Этот оборот является присоединительным (союз И равен союзу ПРИЧЕМ) и его надо обособлять? Вот по этому плану и надо строить ответ. Автор может неверно определить или назвать грамматику, поэтому ваша задача - поправить его. Вы даете один вариант, так запишите его,  правильно назовите, а потом приводите примеры. В примечании можете дать второй вариант, доработанный вами.

Comment: Ответ - это тоже текст, и его надо строить по общим правилам (которые еще в школе изучают), соблюдая принципы построения, следуя какому-то плану. А ваш ответ больше похож на предварительные заметки для ответа. Как мне кажется, мои ответы соответствуют определенной логике по своей структуре.